# Avoiding multicollinearity with dummy encoding of ordinal variable

Tags: multicollinearity, ordinal-data, negative-binomial-distribution, categorical-encoding, mixed-type-data

I was having trouble finding this exact circumstance; hopefully I haven't missed an obvious previous answer.

I have a target variable, `Y` (discrete counts), and two potential regressors, `A` (discrete counts) and `B` (continuous). There's an obvious, necessary causal relationship `A -> B` from the data generating process, and `B` is in fact highly correlated with `A`. (`R ~= .95`)

My aim in the analysis is to determine whether `B` is a significant factor in addition to `A`, so the collinearity is problematic. My first pass (feel free to suggest principled alternatives if this seems kafka; not a stats wiz yet) is to fit a negative binomial regression essentially as `Y ~ A + B`, and determine whether the value fit to `B` has a significant value.

However, the collinearity makes the regression suspect if the ordinal variable `A` is treated as a continuous variable. In this circumstance, is it acceptable and useful to treat `A` as a categorical variable using dummy encoding?

At a glance, this seems to ensure `B` can't be collinear with any level of `A`. But that seems suspiciously like a free lunch to me - am I missing something that may be problematic here?

(I am aware of dummy trap, but unless I'm mistaken, that seems like a separate and easily avoided encoding issue...)

Comment: Can you please give some more details? What does your vars represent? how many ordinal categories? Sample size? Without contextual info only some generalities can be said. But: Think about using a quadratic term (for your ordinal variable), or spline it. Dummy coding can also work.